# jquery tablesorter highlight selected row until another row is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tablesorter

I'm using the jQuery tablesorter library along with jQuery UI dialog. The first column in each row is a link that opens the record in a modal dialog window. What I want to accomplish is to highlight the row when that link is clicked and have that row remain highlighted until another link is clicked. This will allow the user to easily see which row had been clicked after closing the modal window. I've tried adding/removing a highlighting class when the link is clicked, but it has no effect. E.g.:

```
    $("edit_" + myID).click(function(){
       $("tr_" + myID).addClass("highlight");
    });
```

The behavior I'm looking for is somewhat illustrated by this datatables example: https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

That example of course doesn't include the action to open the modal window, but supposing it did and that row highlighting remained until the modal is closed, that's what I'm looking for.

Does anyone know if this is possible with tablesorter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See the "Focus highlight only" example [here](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-css-highlighting.html). The CSS can be modified to achieve the exact effect desired.

Comment: thanks for the response. I did try that before and went back and tried it again to verify. The problem is with the opening and closing of the modal window. When that modal window is closed the highlighting is gone, so the user can't tell which row they were just on. In any case I've migrated the application to datatables so I no longer need to resolve this. Not really sure how to close this question out though...